# Save a Contact 7 Form to complete later

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Is it possible for my users to fill a part of my form, save it, and then come back later and finish to fill the form entirely without losing all the data they add before ?

I used Contact 7 Form on Wordpress with S2Members.

Thank you.

Fabien

Comment: yes, with cookies.

Comment: I try to do that with sisyphus.js, but I have a problem with the implementation. See the comments below the next answer. Do you have a clue for my issue ? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [commercial plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/contact-form-7-auto-save-progress/22449041) or do it yourself by saving the user input data in the browsers **LocalStorage**.

> LocalStorage allows Javascript websites and apps to store and access data from the browser with no expiration date.

In order to save the users input data you could use a javascript library such as [sisyphus-js](https://sisyphus-js.herokuapp.com/) for handling the browsers LocalStorage and attach the function to the form page, example:

```
function saveFormData() {
    // The page where you have your form
    if ( is_page( 'page_for_your_form' ) ) {
        // Load the sisyphus-js for saving form data to local storage
        wp_enqueue_script( 'sisyphus-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/path_to_sisyphus.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
        ?>
            <script>
                $( function() {
                    // You can also attach this function to a button via ie. onClick
                    $( "form" ).sisyphus(); 
                } );
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'saveFormData' );
```

*Code goes into your themes functions.php file*

Comment: Thank you. I try your code, but I have an error in my Console :
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):30

Comment: I pass through this issue with this code :
jQuery(document).ready(function()

Now I have another problem : 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 

I try to figure out ! Maybe Contact 7 Form doesn't work with Sisyphus...

Comment: Try replacing all $ with jQuery

Comment: I had already replace $ by jQuery. 

Here my entire function.php code. I can't find what is wrong ! 

function saveFormData() {
    // The page where you have your form
    if ( is_page( 'note-de-frais-bureau' ) ) {
        // Load the sisyphus-js for saving form data to local storage
        wp_enqueue_script( 'sisyphus.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sisyphus.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
        ?>
            <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($)

jQuery( "#myformID" ).sisyphus(); 

} );

Comment: Make sure that the file sisyphus.js exists in your theme folder - `wp-content/themes/your-theme/js/sisyphus.js` what happends if you run: jQuery( "form" ).sisyphus(); in the console?

Comment: the file is at the right place. 
When I run sisyphus in the console, everything works, but this is weird :

identifier: "[id=contact-form-1234][name=undefined],[id=undefined][name=undefined]"

Comment: I was wondering if Contact 7 Form Shortcode is not the problem... Have ever heard of an incompatibility between Contact 7 Form and Sisyphus on the web ?